# Which of password for grub, encryt /boot or secure boot is the most secure and best from a privacy perspective?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, security, grub2, grub

As the wiki says, you can set a [password for grub](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Password_protection_of_GRUB_menu). Moreover, it seems to be possible to [encrypt /boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Encrypted_/boot). Moreover, I hear that bootloader can be made [secure boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot#shim_with_key_and_GRUB).
Which method is the best way to focus on security and privacy?I'd also like to see the differences explained, if possible.
t's a laptop.professional level protection against industrial espionage, or government secrets　cuz　I'd like to protect it at this level because there's so much seizure and state surveillance on interstate travel these days.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question and give us a bit more detail about what sort of threat you are worried about. Things like whether this is a machine many people have access to, if it is a desktop or a laptop, and just generally what level of paranoia ("normal" person with an interest in basic privacy, or professional level protection against industrial espionage, or government secrets etc.).

Comment: thx answerd　It's a laptop.professional level protection against industrial espionage, or government secrets　cuz　I'd like to protect it at this level because there's so much seizure and state surveillance on interstate travel these days.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include these details. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning.

Answer (score 0):

If the hacker has (had) physical access to your system, you're f-ed regardless (think of hardware backdoors, changed bootloader, etc.). If you just want to protect your data from possible prying eyes, having a non-encrypted /boot will save you from a lot of unnecessary hassle.

My /boot and EFI system partitions are not encrypted but everything else is.